# How do I locally test haproxy when routing based on host name?

Tags: automated-tests, haproxy

I have a fairly complex haproxy configuration that routes to backends based on the host of the request (via acl + hdr_dom). If I want to test the configuration locally, I have to change the resolution of the hosts I want to test (for example, by changing hosts file to resolve host to 127.0.0.1). I can then use wget or curl to test the haproxy configuration locally, and reset the hosts file afterward.

However, I want to have automated tests, and changing system level things in an automated test makes me nervous. Before I go down the path of changing the hosts file in an automatic way, is there a way to tell haproxy "pretend this request was made to xxx.yyy.com"? Is there some other approach I can take?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there a way to tell haproxy "pretend this request was made to xxx.yyy.com"?

I believe that's the wrong question.  The correct question is "How can I tell curl that example.com's IP address is 127.0.0.1?"

The answer is `--resolve`.

```
curl -v --resolve example.com:80:127.0.0.1 http://example.com
curl -v --resolve example.com:443:127.0.0.1 https://example.com
```

This preloads the answer (127.0.0.1) into curl's DNS cache for that invocation only, which apparently tricks it into not actually doing a DNS lookup, because it thinks it already did.  Instead, it will connect to the IP address you specify.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I knew there must be something like this out there

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Micheal above is the best way to approach this (as it actually goes through the DNS lookup). If that doesn't work, I found that setting the Host HTTP Header to the server also works. For example, in Windows/PowerShell the following works.

```
iwr http://localhost:8090/testjudge.aspx?version=1 -headers @{Host="xxx.yyy.com"}
```

Linux's native curl had a different syntax, but the idea is the same. See [This post on how to do this on various platforms](https://samchounwork.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/powershell-equivalent-to-curl-command-with-host-header/)

Comment: This does work -- mostly -- but not when you're using HTTPS and SNI.  Using the `--resolve` trick is essentially the same as hacking your hosts file, though less intrusive.